# ruby-on-rails: Seeding-data strategies (or loading test data into developer database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures, seeding

I want to clear and re-load my developer database (Ruby on rails) frequently.

Of course, I can manually add the data via the web page but I was wondering if anyone has any strategies for this type of testing.

(I already have unit, functional and integration tests, fyi)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Create a `seed.yml` file in `db` directory. Add a YAML document for each model you want to create. This document should contain a list of hash. Each hash should contain model attributes.

```
  users:
      -   login: jake
          password: jake123
          password_confirmation: jake123
          first_name: Jake
          last_name: Driver

      -   login: Jane
          password: jane123
          password_confirmation: jane123
          first_name: Jane
          last_name: McCain

  categories:

  products:
```

In your seed.rb file

```
seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seed.yml')
config = YAML::load_file(seed_file)
User.transaction do 
  config.keys.each{ |key| key.classify.constantize.create(config[key]) }
end
```

I find it easier to modify the seed data in the YML file. Application that I have built is deployed by a different team. They like this approach too.

To clear the data I have a rake task in lib\tasks directory. I run the rake task as `app:flush`.

```
namespace :app do
  desc "Flush all the seed data "
  task :flush => :environment do
    config = YAML::load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seed.yml'))
    User.transaction do 
      config.keys.each{ |table| truncate_table(table)}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Time to look at "fixtures" and "seeding data" ;-) I am not good enough to give you a clear explanation, but googling those two keys should give you all you need.

Check these out: http://derekdevries.com/2009/04/13/rails-seed-data/
http://lptf.blogspot.com/2009/09/seed-data-in-rails-234.html